# Rectangle appearing not where it should

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to write a Java application in which I could draw rectangles on an image(JLabel). The problem is that the rectangle appears not where it should. It starts at the top left corner of the screen and not the component with the image..

I get the x and y coordinates for the starting point like this:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("X:"+e.getX()+"Y:"+e.getY());
}
```

When the mouse is dragged I get the end x,y and call repaint:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(label)) {
            System.out.println("X:"+e.getX()+"Y:"+e.getY());
            endX = e.getX();
            endY = e.getY();
            repaint();
        }
    }
```

So how do I make it get X and Y relative to the label? And not the window? I want 0,0 to be the start of label.

The mouse listeners are added to the label:

```
label.addMouseListener(this);
label.addMouseMotionListener(this);
```

The label is added to a panel for layout porpuse.

UPDATE: I tried printint out the coordinates. It seems they are alright.. But the rectangle is still not where I want it to be. I suspect that it is painted on the JFrame. 
How do I paint something ON the label?

SOLDVED: the problem was where I would never have expected. I just got a graphics object off of my label and drew with it.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Of course, one way might be to add the listener to the label, rather than the parent component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So how do I make it get X and Y relative to the label? And not the window?

It sounds to me like you are adding the MouseListener to the window.

Add the MouseListener to the label and the mouse points will be relative to the label.

Edit:

> How do I paint something ON the label?

Override the paintComponent() method of the JLabel.

You can also check out [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example that draws rectangles on a JPanel. The code would be the same for a JLabel. The `DrawOnComponent` example would be the code to look at.

If you still have problem then post your SSCCE and quit making people guess what you are doing.

Comment: **label.addMouseListener(this);**
**label.addMouseMotionListener(this);** I am adding them to the label

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the width and height of the figure

```
endX = e.getX() + (figureWidth / 2);
endY = e.getY() + (figureHeight / 2);
```

Comment: I did not quite understand what you meant by "figure" ?