# Rectangle is not drawn on top

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I have a class "Map" which extends JPanel. I add it to a class that extends a JFrame.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int width = Math.abs(startX - endX);
        int height= Math.abs(startY - endY);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(startX, startY, width, height);
    }
```

My class "Map" also contains a label with an image in it. If the image is smalled than the window, when I draw a rectangle it is seen. 
In short, it is under the label.

Comment: `I want to be able to draw rectangles on the jlabel(which is a picture).`, I already answered that in your last posting (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20575316/131872). You extend your JLable (not a JPanel) and do the custom painting in the paintComponent() method of the label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`paintComponent` is the "bottom" of the paint chain, so anything painted here will appear below everything else.

A better solution might be to add the `Map` panel to the label (setting the `JLabel`'s layout manager appropriately).

Or, create a "base" panel, set it's layout manager to use a `OverlayLayout` manager and add the `JLabel` and `Map` panel to it.

This will, of course, all depend on what it is you want to achieve...

**Updated with "Panel on Label" example**

Basically, this takes a `JLabel`, sets an icon (as the background image), set it's layout as `BorderLayout` and then adds a `JPanel` on to it.

Remember, `JPanel` is opaque by default, so you need to make it transparent ;)

[image: Panel on label]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class OverlayLabel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new OverlayLabel();
    }

    public OverlayLabel() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/image"))));
                    background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    background.add(new TestPane());

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(background);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - 20) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - 20) / 2;
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

**Updated with example of `OverlayLayout`**

`OverlayLayout` basically uses the components x/y alignment to make determinations about how best it should place the individual components

[image: OverlayLayout]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class OverlayLabel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new OverlayLabel();
    }

    public OverlayLabel() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/image"))));
                    background.setAlignmentX(0.5f);
                    background.setAlignmentY(0.5f);

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(frame.getContentPane()));
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.add(background);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - 20) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - 20) / 2;
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

And finally, if none of that is working for you, you could use `JLayeredPane` as the base, which will allow you to determine the z-order of each component...

See [How to use layered panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for more details...

Comment: You can add a panel to a JLabel? :/ I want to be able to draw rectangles on the jlabel(which is a picture).

Comment: `JLabel` extends from `JComponent` which extends from `Container`, so yes, it is just a container like `JPanel`.  Just remember though, `JLabel` has no default layout manager and you won't be able to control (to any great level of percision) this position of the icon

Comment: Okay, so I added a "Map" object to a label and set its layout to "OverlayLayout", nothing changed... What does OverlayLayout do?

Comment: It basically acts a little like `BorderLayout`, but puts everything in the `CENTER` position (unlike `BorderLayout` which only allows a single component to sit within a given position)

Comment: And if you're going to add the panel to the label, I might use `BorderLayout` instead ;)